# Power BI apply DAX to column AFTER aggregation Elapsed Time hh:mm:ss

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have been struggling to get Elapsed Time values to work the way I'd like them to.

My data is coming from MYSQL and contains a start and end datetime

(format is `7/27/2018 12:16:12 AM`)

I created a custom column using the Power Query Editor that contains this simple formula:

`=[TimeCompleted]-[TimeStarted]`

I then changed the type in the column to Duration which leaves the values in this format:

`4.00:01:37` (which translates to 4 days, 1 minute, 37 seconds as I understand)

That all seems fine - when I view the values in a table however, the amounts are different. They display as decimal numbers (like `6.9444444`)

I believe they're in the format of "days" which is basically like `6.9444444` or `0.0000324`

When I put these values in a table to view, it might show that the elapsed time is `0.5` (which translates to 12 hours?)

I have a DAX formula that can convert a value to `hh:mm:ss`, but I would like to apply this *after* I have aggregated the data.

For example, my table with Elapsed Time looks like this:

[image: ElapsedTime]

I would like to leave it just like this, but format the column so that it is in the format of `hh:mm:ss` for display purposes.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

As suggested, I created a measure that summed the ElapsedTime and it seemed to work just fine (except that anything > 24 hours would wrap around).

The solution I went with is to just add the hours to the beginning yourself if it is greater than one day:

```
ElapsedTimeHMS = 
IF(
    SUM('checklists allqachecklists'[ElapsedTime]) >= 1,
    INT(SUM('checklists allqachecklists'[ElapsedTime]))*24 + INT(FORMAT(SUM('checklists allqachecklists'[ElapsedTime]),"hh")) & ":" & 
    FORMAT(SUM('checklists allqachecklists'[ElapsedTime]), "mm:ss"),
    FORMAT(SUM('checklists allqachecklists'[ElapsedTime]), "hh:mm:ss"
)
```

The result for `1.07` becomes `25:12:45` (before it was `01:12:45`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. If your measure is something like `SUM(Table1[Elapsed Time])`, then you can just add a formatting wrapper to it.

```
Formatted Measure = FORMAT(SUM(Table1[Elapsed Time]), "hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I'm just using the automatic aggregation tools by dragging it to a table - I don't know if it's generating its own formula?

Comment: For example, I drag a list of users over to the table and the list of users appear. When I click "Elapsed Time", it sums them up in that format, but there's no way for me to edit the formula itself because it's all automatic. I could probably add a custom measure in some way, but it's aggregating them by their name? I was hoping to have it all work automatically and not have to create these custom columns - just worrying how they'd respond to the various filters

Comment: Maybe I'm just an idiot, but this seems to work just fine - thanks so much!

Comment: It doesn't account for days though - anything over 24 hours just wraps around. Any solution there?

Comment: I figured out a solution - posting above